# HTTP or HTTPS Error

Tags: swift

I was wondering should I put a s behind the http in this url, because I keep getting an error.

Here is the code.

```
("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should prefer the HTTPS version if possible.

However, I believe the error you are getting is not because of HTTPS, it's actually an error with your request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US"><description>Query syntax error(s) [line 1:6 expecting fields_or_star got ' ']</description></error>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple has made the change that you have to use HTTPS or enter an exception in your info.plist.

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This allows all http traffic, but I would suggest strongly to only do this for testing.

See this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).